# How to add data from column in a data frame to a corpus based on a value from another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, corpus

So I have a data frame that I would like to put the CorpusText column into a corpus based on the value of another column. (The last 4 columns were achieved through the following:

```
usersDF$pos.bool <- usersDF$score >= 1
usersDF$neg.bool <- usersDF$score <= -1

usersDF$pos = as.numeric( usersDF$pos.bool )
usersDF$neg = as.numeric( usersDF$neg.bool )

usersDF

Name    CorpusText   score      pos     neg   pos.bool neg.bool  
Rob       Text        -4         0       1     FALSE    TRUE
Sam       Text        -3         0       1     FALSE    TRUE
Lynda     Text         1         1       0     TRUE     FALSE    
Robert    Text         2         1       0     TRUE     FALSE
RJ        Text         6         1       0     TRUE     FALSE
Rob       Text        -2         0       1     FALSE    TRUE
Bert      Text        -1         0       1     FALSE    TRUE
```

I'm interested in creating positive and negative sentiment corpus and I thought it could be achieved through  the following:

```
library(tm)
pos.corpus <-Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText, usersDF$pos.bool=="TRUE"))
neg.corpus <-Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText, usersDF$neg.bool=="TRUE"))
```

OR

```
pos.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText, usersDF$pos=="1"))
neg.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText, usersDF$neg =="1"))
```

But I get the following error every time:

```
Error in VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText, usersDF$... == "...")
unused argument (usersDF$... == "...")
```

What is the correct way to pull the data from my CorpusText column into a positive corpus based on the pos or pos.bool column and likewise for a negative corpus based on the neg or neg.bool column?

Comment: It sounds like you just want `pos.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText[usersDF$pos==1]))` and `neg.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText[usersDF$neg ==1]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brain freeze.  Thanks to @josilber, I realized that I needed was `[]`.

So:

```
pos.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText[usersDF$pos==1]))
```

and

```
neg.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(usersDF$CorpusText[usersDF$neg ==1]))
```

Was the solution.